# twitter api : only the number of tweets

Tags: api, twitter

I just want to have the numbers of tweets with the hashtag #zzzrrererererfdd

And i don't find how to do that with the twitter api. I don't want all the things like the user etc ...

If someone have any idea how just do that without parsing all the results.

Thanks

Bussiere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the Twitter API.

You can use the `search/tweets` API endpoint to find tweets with a particular hashtag (by supplying a hashtag as the `q`param), but the response data does not include any metadata about tweet count. You'll need to loop through and count the tweets yourself.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets